# how to convert a nested object to json

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jpa, gson

i have a list of customer objects. customer object contains order objects. since there is a @onetomany relationship in customer to order.

customer:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "owner",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<OrderTable> order;
```

order:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "OWNER_ID")
    private Customer owner;
```

when i try to pass the list of all customer objects to the browser, it fails to convert the list to json.

```
 my svlet---
 try {

            //int sucsess=handlesOrder.addOrder();

            //int sucsess=handlesOrder.insertOrder();

            //orderlist = handlesOrder.getorders();
            if (Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("type")) == 1) {
                custlist = handlesOrder.getCustomer();

                orderlist=handlesOrder.getAllorders();

                Gson gsonObj = new Gson(); -- 1
                String jsonString = gsonObj.toJson(orderlist);--2
                response.getWriter().write(jsonString);
                response.setContentType("application/json");
                response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }finally {
            out.close();
        }
```

after the line 2 it is jumping to the finally... not an exeption

Comment: `it fails to convert the list to json` - you mean you are getting some error?

Comment: yes. it fails to convert orderlist to json string

Comment: then what is the exception and its stacktrace

Comment: i have update the question.. plz hav a look

Comment: I don't think your code goes directly to finally block after line 2, definitely you should get an exception in between.

Comment: i debugged it, but there is no exceptions

Comment: If you not getting any exception then try out these changes because sometimes joining of table creates issue ... .                      @ManyToOne(fetch =      FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "OWNER_ID")
    private Customer owner;